# Starting WPF window from another application addin

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, autodesk-inventor

I have created an Autodesk inventor addin. I have another class library with a wpf window. I am trying to show that wpf window from the addin on a button click.

```
override protected void ButtonDefinition_OnExecute(NameValueMap context)
    {
        try
        {
            TubesheetTool.MainWindow tsTool = new TubesheetTool.MainWindow();
            tsTool.CADProgram = new InventorCADProgram(InventorApplication, tsTool);
            tsTool.Show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message );
            //HTEventLog.LogError(e, "HTInventorAddIn");
        }
    }
```

I am sure that I have added all the required references.However when the inventor runs and on button click, I get this error: "Could not find file 'C:\language=ENU'"
The strange thing is that the same code runs fine when using Visual Studio and interop.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how the button is created? Is this a ribbon button?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your WPF window is defined in an assembly which is not the same as the addin. I've experienced some problems with this kind of configuration in a previous project. The only solution I've found is to put all the XAML files in the main assembly. It seems that WPF has some trouble for loading the resources.